# Comparing stored data in a column to an existing value

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a column called favid. I am trying to pull and compare the data in that column to an existing value:

```
<?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE favid=$favid"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
echo $row['favid']; };?>
```

I also have an existing value:

```
$x
```

But when I do something like this it doesn't work:

```
<?php if($row['favid'] == $x){?>
Do this...
<?php } else { ?>
Do nothing...
<?php}?>
```

I realize the data in the column somehow isn't pulled out. What should be done for this to work?

Comment: you think `$favid` should be filled by just putting it in a SQL string?

Comment: Are you connecting to a database?  Passing your SQL statement to it?  Retrieving an answer?  Read any documentation perhaps? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php

Comment: Yes, I am connected to the database. I can store data to that column, no problem. I am having issues retrieving that data. How is it done?

Comment: In first chapter, please try using this query:
`mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE favid='{$favid}'");`

Comment: And witch type of data is stored in the column?

Comment: @AleksandrsRudzitis they are numbers like 11345 11346 11347 etc. If you were doing this, how would you make it work? All I want to do is compare $x to the data in that column, find a matching one so that the statement **if $row['favid'] == $x do this else do that** would work.

Comment: I realize that should be pulled out as an array and then used in that statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I assume you already connected to DB.

```
<?php

$x = 1;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE favid='$favid'") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        if ($row["existing_column_name"] == $x)
        {
            echo "Yes";
        } else
        {
            echo "No";
        }
    }
} else
{
    echo "Nothing was found";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$x = 100500; // integer for example
$CID = mysql_connect("host","user","pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db_name");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ajaxfavourites WHERE favid='{$favid}'", $CID);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
    if (intval($row["some_existing_column_name"])==$x){
        print "Is equals!";
    } else {
        print "Is different!";
    }
}
?>
```

Please be informed that `mysql_connect` and other functions with the prefix of `mysql_` is deprecated and can be removed in the next versions of PHP.

Comment: what "some_existing_column_name" should be? Is it favid (since the column's name is favid)?